# What list of words do you use when creating a language?

Tags: conlang-creation, vocabulary

What word list do you use when creating a language? Is there a conlang word list?

**P.S** I know that this question is kinda subjective, but I think that it will be quite useful for conlangers.

Comment: You might want to check out [This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/54843/word-lists-for-constructed-languages) on [worldbuilding.se], which is essentially a "cross-site duplicate".